# Postgres 9.6.2 not stopping on Windows. Any idea?

Tags: postgresql, windows, postgresql-9.6

So, I've got Postgres 9.6.2 installed on Windows 10 64bit, and, when I start Windows, 2 things **might** happen:

1. The server starts normally. This is the most common one.
2. The server starts in an inconsistent way that hangs if you try to connect to it, like with `psql`. Stopping the service is not possible through the `Services` app. See screenshot.

When it starts inconsist, I can't stop the service. See:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0LRG.png]

It stays forever in a  `Stopping` state.

I'm not an experienced DBA. Any idea on how to solve this or find the reason?

Comment: Is anyone connected to it?

Comment: @EvanCarroll. Thanks for the reply. It's just me on a development machine.

Comment: Do you have any logs showing what happens when it starts and when you try to stop it ? Did you do some peculiar postgresql.conf configuration ?

Answer (score 2):

Connect with psql and type this commmand

```
show log_destination;
```

this will display where logs are. If the output is `EVENTLOG`, then check Windows Event Viewer for any message from postgresql. I don't think log_destination is `CSVLOG` nor `SYSLOG`, so the last possible value is `STDERR`. In this case I don't think you may get the messages.
In order to change your configuration and use event log, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/event-log-registration.html .

Once you know where the log is, check its content and you should be able to find the cause of your problem.

Comment: @miracle173 thanks, I just corrected these errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely find your log as eppesuig taold you.

To stop your server, did you try stopping it with pg_ctl ?

You could find this documentation usefull: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-ctl.html

You might want to try `pg_ctl stop [-W] [-t seconds] [-s] [-D datadir] -m smart`